# Proof of the Density Theorem using contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I just started studying Introduction to Real Analysis for the first time. I'm sorry if the following attempt contains elementary mistakes.

The Density Theorem states that if $x$ and $y$ are any real numbers with $x < y$, then there exists a rational number $r$ such that $x < r < y$.

In the book, they use the Archimedean Property to prove the theorem, but I'm thinking of trying to solve it using contradiction as follows:

*""Suppose, by contradiction, that $x < y$ but for all rationals $r$, $r \geq y$ or $r \leq x$ (simply the negation of the wanted conclusion).*

*Case 1: If $r \geq y$, then $y$ is a lower bound of $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is unbounded, then this case is impossible.*

*Case 2: If $r \leq x$, then $x$ is an upper bound of $\mathbb{Q}$. Similarly, $\mathbb{Q}$ being unbounded implies this is impossible.*

*Case 3: If $ r \geq y$ and $r \leq x$ then, since $x < y$, $r \geq y > r$ which is impossible (also note that Cases 1 and 2 eliminate Case 3 completely).*

*Since all cases are impossible, the Density Theorem must be true.""*

Is this a valid proof? If not, why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The negation would say for each rational $r$, either $r\ge y$ or $r\le x$. (Not that all rationals are at least $y$ or all are at most $x$.)

Comment: Rationals exist both at the left of $x$ and the right of $y$. Therefore neither $y$ is a lower bound nor $x$ is an upper bound for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 5):

Good try, but not really a valid proof. Imagine for a second, that $\mathbb{Q}$ has no rationals between $1$ and $2$. Clearly, $1$ is not a lower bound for $\mathbb{Q}$ since $1/2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $2$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb{Q}$ since $5 \in \mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: To expand on this answer a little, the statement $\forall\,r\in {\Bbb Q}, (r\le x \text{ or  } y\le r)$ is not the same statement as $(\forall \,r\in {\Bbb Q}\ r\le x)$ or $(\forall\,r\in {\Bbb Q} \ y\le r)$.